# Swipe gesture in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

How swipe guesture to be implemented in phonegap android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery mobile you can use the built in event `swipe`.

[Documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)

E.g.:

```
$("#myContainer").on("swipe", function(event) {
    alert("I got swiped!");
});
```

If you're using jQuery UI take a look at [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/).

> jQuery UI Touch Punch is a small hack that enables the use of touch events on sites using the jQuery UI user interface library.

[Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) is also a worthable mention here. It can be used in vanilla JavaScript as well as a jQuery plugin.

> Hammer supports Tap, DoubleTap, Swipe, Drag, Pinch, and Rotate gestures. Each gesture triggers useful events and eventData.

If you don't want to use a plugin take a look at the [following](http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/swipesensejs.html).

Comment: can you give me a suggestion. How can i stop when i swipe the 1st page to the direction right, it is moving to the last page and when I am on the last page If I swipe left it is moving to first page.I need to stop it.How can i do that.can you tell me...

Comment: in Hammer.js swipe stops at left and right side.Exactly that logic I want